# Gmail error message disappeared before I could read it

Tags: gmail

I clicked "send" on a message in Gmail, and one of those black error message/info boxes popped up in the lower-left corner. I wasn't expecting it, and the length of error text was somewhat substantial, so I, unfortunately, wasn't able to read it before it disappeared.

Is there some sort of error message log that Gmail keeps? Is there any way to figure out what the message said not that it has disappeared?

I'm rather concerned about this, as it was a "why haven't you responded to my previous email" email, and if it was some message about difficulties in delivering, then that's something I really need to know. (From the quick glance I did get, there might have been something about "labeled as spam" in the message, but I'm not 100% sure and I don't know what context that was in.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Gmail does not have any error log viewer for its end-users (you). Best you can do is to repeat the action which led you to that error and PrintScreen it when it pops out again.